# What do I need to do to sort all the records (for suppose 1000) and return top 50 records in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr

I have total 1000 records and I need to sort all the records based on one property and need to get top 60 from the sorted 1000 records.

Comment: sort by the property then limit 60

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic Solr usage, and I'd strongly suggest [at least trying to look at the documentation first](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html).

For sorting your documents:

> The `sort` parameter arranges search results in either ascending (asc) or descending (desc) order. The parameter can be used with either numerical or alphabetical content. The directions can be entered in either all lowercase or all uppercase letters (i.e., both asc or ASC). (`sort=property asc`)

And for the number of documents returned:

> You can use the `rows` parameter to paginate results from a query. The parameter specifies the maximum number of documents from the complete result set that Solr should return to the client at one time. (`rows=60`)